# Change the color of a tikz tree to blue

Tags: color, tikz-trees

```
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[   level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm},   edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
  >=latex]
\node[root] {Compresseur}   child {node[level 2] (c2) {Compresseur rotatif}}   child {node[level 2] (c3) {Compresseur alternatif}};

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 3}]
\node [below of = c2, xshift=15pt] (c21) {Centrifuge}; \node [below of
= c21] (c22) {Axial}; \node [below of = c22] (c23) {A palettes}; \node [below of = c23] (c24) {A vis}; \node [below of = c24] (c25) {Scroll}; \node [below of = c24] (c25) {A lobes};
\node [below of = c3, xshift=15pt] (c31) {A piston}; \node [below of = c31] (c32) {Hydrolique};
\end{scope}

\foreach \value in {1,...,5}   \draw[->] (c2.195) |- (c2\value.west);
\foreach \value in {1,2}   \draw[->] (c3.195) |- (c3\value.west); \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: your code is not compileable

Answer (score 4):

This is not a full answer because the question is not very clear, let alone compilable. What do you want to turn blue? If it is the lines, look at

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[root/.style={rounded corners,draw,fill=green!50},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm},  
level 2/.style={sibling distance=40mm,rounded corners,draw,fill=green!80}, 
level 3/.style={sibling distance=40mm,draw,fill=red!30},   
 edge from parent/.style={->,draw,blue},
  >=latex,every node/.append style={drop shadow},font=\sffamily]

\node[root] {Compresseur}   child {node[level 2] (c2) 
{Compresseur rotatif}}   
child {node[level 2] (c3) {Compresseur alternatif}};

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={level 3}]
\node [below of = c2, xshift=15pt] (c21) {Centrifuge}; 
\node [below of = c21] (c22) {Axial}; 
\node [below of = c22] (c23) {A palettes}; 
\node [below of = c23] (c24) {A vis}; 
\node [below of = c24] (c25) {Scroll}; 
\node [below of = c25] (c26) {A lobes};

\node [below of = c3, xshift=15pt] (c31) {A piston}; 
\node [below of = c31] (c32) {Hydrolique};
\end{scope}

\foreach \value in {1,...,6}   
{\draw[blue,->] (c2.195) |- (c2\value.west);}

\foreach \value in {1,2}   
{\draw[blue,->] (c3.195) |- (c3\value.west);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I had to guess the styles of the nodes as they are not part of your code.